# how to plot the data in gnuplot you inserted in c using scanf

Tags: c, plot, scanf, gnuplot

Sorry for my Broken English.

I just started to learn coding so I practically know nothing about it.

I am trying to make a program that you insert the data file using scanf in c and plot in gnuplot.

the program I have made is as follows.

```
  #include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  char filename[10];
  FILE *fp;

  printf("the name of the file?\n");
  scanf("%s", &filename);
  fp=fopen(filename, "r");

  fclose(fp);

  FILE *gp;

  gp=popen("gnuplot -persist", "w");
  fprintf(gp, "set autoscale x\n");
  fprintf(gp, "set autoscale y\n");
  fprintf(gp, "filename=%s", &filename);
  fprintf(gp, "gnoplot \"filename\" using 1:2 w p\n");

  pclose(gp);

  return 0;
}
```

and the result is as follows.

```
bash-4.1$ ./a.out
the name of the file?
data11.dat

p�gnoplot "filename" using 1:2 w p
                            ^
         line 0: invalid character
```

and the data I tried to plot is as follows.

```
1 3
2 4
3 5
4 5
5 7
```

I have found that you can plot the data using while(fscanf), but the problem is I have to plot another function in addition to that data in one image.

I googled a lot but I cannot find a solution.

Please help me!

*) OK there were some good suggestions from @Gill Bates and @melpomene so I edited my code and excuted again. The result seems a little better but not perfect. Thanks guys

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  char filename[30];
  FILE *fp;

  printf("the name of the file?\n");
  scanf("%s", &filename);
  fp=fopen(filename, "r");

  fclose(fp);

  FILE *gp;

  gp=popen("gnuplot -persist", "w");
  fprintf(gp, "set autoscale x\n");
  fprintf(gp, "set autoscale y\n");
  fprintf(gp, "filename=%s", &filename);
  fprintf(gp, "plot \"filename\" using 1:2 w p\n");

  pclose(gp);

  return 0;
}
```

the result

```
bash-4.1$ ./a.out
the name of the file?
data11.dat
         line 0: undefined variable: data11
```

I guess I have to figure out how to call the data file from c to gnuplot.

**)I think I solved a problem, in a way, by using plot '-'

Comment: Try replacing `gnuplot "filename ... "` with `plot "filename" ...`.

Comment: There's a buffer overflow. You're trying to store 11 chars in `char filename[10];`. (This is why you don't use `scanf` `%s`.)

Comment: `fprintf(gp, "filename=\"%s\"", &filename);`

Comment: @GillBates Thanks , I made a mistake.

Comment: @melpomene I didn't know that, Thanks!

Comment: @Christoph Thanks a lot for your help!